# closures javascript help to understand example

Tags: javascript

```
    var Counter = (function() {
  var privateCounter = 0;
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }
  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  };   
})();

alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 0 */
Counter.increment();
Counter.increment();
alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 2 */
Counter.decrement();
alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 1 */
```

can you explain me this code line by line please? I understand that a;; methods have an asses to variable counter shared variable but it seems like magic anyway cause we say that it equls to zero in the beggining

Comment: what do you want to understand?

Comment: Function is an object that has it's properties and methods. You're calling it's methods that change it's "private" property. This property had the value of "0" on it's initialization, but you don't give it a value each time you call one of objects methods, you just change the old one.

Comment: if i remember correctly... isn't this the example found in the MDN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Counter = (function() {
```

This is the creation of the object named `Counter`. It is created through anonymous self-invoking function. But because the function is self-invoking, giving it uppercase name is not recommended.

```
  var privateCounter = 0;
```

"Private" variable `privateCounter` is being set. It's private in a sense that you cannot access it directly from the outside. It is created in a scope of an anonymous function, and that gives it separate scope from it's containing function - `Counter`. That is the reason you cannot access it from the outside, e.g. `Counter.privateCounter === undefined`. Note: whenever you try to access `this` from an anonymous function, the result will be `window` object, but you cannot access it with `window.privateCounter`.

```
  function changeBy(val) {
    privateCounter += val;
  }
```

This is a "private" method, `Counter.changeBy() === undefined`. That is same as doing `var changeBy = function(val){}`. If you want to make property or method "public" (accessible from the outside), you have to define them like this:

```
this.publicCounter = 0;
this.changeBy = function(val)...
```

This is the usual way to do it, when your object is not created through an anonymous function (check the above comment on `this`), but in this case you create them like this:

```
  return {
    increment: function() {
      changeBy(1);
    },
    decrement: function() {
      changeBy(-1);
    },
    value: function() {
      return privateCounter;
    }
  };
```

These remain the "public" methods of `Counter`, they are a part of the scope of `Counter` object. You can access them like you do in alerts.

```
})();
```

This means the function is self-invoking, e.g. it is being executed immediately.

Now, before I go on... When you start your script, object `Counter` gets created, since it's a self-invoking function. That creates a scope of that object and another scope of it's anonymous function (with one "private" property, and one "private" method). Three returned methods are in a scope of `Counter`, but they can access the scope of it's anonymous function, even though that function already returned. That is because those three methods are pointing into that scope, they still have "some business" in there, so the garbage collector won't touch the internal variables. After anonymous function returned, the only way you can access values inside of it is through methods it returned, if there are any. Hope this is clear. Now, let's move on.

```
alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 0 */
```

This calls `value()` method of `Counter` object. This method reaches into the scope of already returned anonymous function, and gives you back the value of a local variable.

```
Counter.increment();
Counter.increment();
```

Again you call a "public" method of your object that can access the local function in the function that had returned.

```
alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 2 */
```

As before. But note that `privateCounter` is in the scope of the function that already returned. You are not creating a new one, just accessing the old one through some methods that have the exclusive right to still see it.

```
Counter.decrement();
alert(Counter.value()); /* Alerts 1 */
```

As before.

Basically, it's like calling a handyman (object) and handyman always comes with his skills ("public" methods and properties) and tools ("private" methods and properties). If you need something done, call the handyman and tell him what to do, which skill to use, but you cannot use his tools without him. And he has he's collection of tools, he doesn't buy new set each time you call him. His pliers are the same old ones you stepped on and broke last time he was in.

Comment: that's funckin awesome answer thank you really))))))))))))))

Comment: *"As I understand it's a mistake in the language."* - Actually, there is no mistake. The scope of `privateCounter` is NOT `window` but the anonymous function scope. It would be `window` if you had defined it as `this.privateCounter` instead of `var privateCounter`.

Comment: *"If you want to make property or method "public" (accessible from the outside), you have to define them like this:"* - If you had defined `this.publicCounter` it would NOT be a public member of the Counter object. Instead, it would be a public member of `window`. The same for `changeBy()`.

Comment: @jackflash I think you're wrong. `privateCounter` is in the scope of `window` (you can check the value of `this` in the debugger). You can think of it as a private property of `window`. But I'm not sure if that is a mistake in the language. And for the second comment, I think you didn't read the next sentence.

Comment: @Zemljoradnik `this` points to `window` that is absolutely correct. But in OP's code `privateCounter` is not defined as a property of `this` (and therefore of `window`) but it is defined as a `var` inside the annonymous function. So, its scope is not `window`, it is the closure body.

Comment: @jackflash We are pointing at the same behavior, just calling it differently. As I said, it acts like being a "private" member of `window` object. Why is that, I don't know. I heard Douglas Crockford calling it a flaw in a language design, but I never got deep into it, so I don't have an opinion on that.

Comment: @Zemljoradnik It is not a private member of `window`. That would mean every `window` method could access it and that is not possible.  It's just a variable defined inside a function (own scope) so it cannot be accessed from a parent scope (`window`). Its behaviour is kind of a private member of `Counter` object.

Comment: @jackflash You are right, my bad. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is all about *scopes*. That code defines an object in a variable called `Counter` but not directly. It defines and calls a function that returns the object (with methods `increment()`, `decrement()`, and `value()`). The scope of that object is where it is created, so it is the anonymous funciton body in first place and then de global namespace. Although the closure is not declared (stored) and it is only called once, the scope remains. So that the object can access the variable `privateCounter` and the method `changeBy()`. And it is the only object that can access those members thus they are called "private".

Answer (score 0):

it's quite straight forward, I'll try to make it clearer, '`counter`' is an object, that contains three functions(`increment`, `decrement` and value) and a variable(`privateCounter`)
when creating counter, the `privateCounter`  is set to zero as an initialization, this is obvious, but what I think made it hard for you is returning three functions together, but think about it as including them into 'counter', now every one of the three functions returns either the value (`value()`), or increments/decrements by a certain number.
now the last 6 lines should make sense, the first line just copies the initial value which is zero, then we increment twice, the `increment()` function increments the internal value twice to 2, and when you perform `value()` again it becomes 2, and `decrement()` does the same. I hope my talk make sense to you.